# css positioning baseline

Tags: css, positioning

I would like to have the dropdown at the same baseline level of Btn1-2 and Btn3 above, *but within the cell*. Basically the opposite as what it is now. What am I missing?  Thanks

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="border:1px solid #000">
        <td>
            <div style="position:relative">
            <input type="button" value="Bt1" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Bt2" /> 
                <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
                    <input type="button" value="Btn3" /> <br />
                    <select>
                        <option>Hello</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have button 3 and the select inside of a div ?

Comment: right, but the thing is that I want the dropdown underneath Btn3

Comment: @xixonia: I guess not, as long as Btn3 and the dropdown are inside the same cell as btn1 and btn2

Comment: In that case if you get rid of the divs entirely, you can use the second half of my solution. If you need the divs, just get rid of the line breaks, and make the divs inline-block. See below.

Comment: @JoshD - since you have no qualms about bad programming I would just whack a `<br/>` before `<input type="button" value="Bt1" />`. This will fix your issue and you won't have to start thinking about how to do things properly.

Comment: @JoshD, nevermind. I didn't realize you wanted it on the right-hand side. Silly me. go with the floating divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you should do this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="border:1px solid #000">
        <td>
            <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="button" value="Bt1" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Bt2" /> 
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
            <input type="button" value="Btn3" />                    
                   <select>
                        <option>Hello</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Set `float` for the two `divs`. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/DnWWy/

Comment: is there a way to have the dropdown under btn3?

Comment: Naveed Ahmad: close, however, now I would like to bring the dropdown at the same level of bt1 and bt2. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the div style from position:absolute; to position:relative; which will keep it inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr style="border:1px solid #000">
    <td>
        <div style="position:relative">
        <input type="button" value="Bt1" />
        <input type="button" value="Bt2" />
            <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
                <input type="button" value="Btn3" />
                <select>
                    <option>Hello</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```